# Unable to use HTML5 FileSystem Api from Google Chrome Extension background.js

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-filesystem

I'm creating a Chrome extension.

Whenever I try to use the following code from an extension page everything works fine:

```
let req = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
req(window.PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, function(fs){
   fs.root.getFile("someName", {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
       //we don't get here
    }
}
```

However when I try to execute it inside the background page script, I get the following error:

```
DOMException: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources.
```

Please help. What's going on?

I want to be able to select files with my chrome extension page and then let the background page actually write those files to the sandboxed persistent storage, so that if the extension is closed my background page can complete writing the files to the file system in the background.

Comment: Might be caused by the user permissions on the real profile directory e.g. if it's a network resource or otherwise restricted. Anyway there is probably no programmatic solution/workaround for this. Also consider reporting on https://crbug.com.